Hashicorp Vault
While I am trying to create Static role in ldap secret Engine i am encountering this Issue.
Command:
vault write ldap/static-role/Developers dn='CN=Jhon,ou=SMDEV-Users,dc=smdev,dc=com' username='Jhon' rotation_period="24h"

Error writing data to ldap/static-role/Developers: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/ldap/static-role/Developers Code:
500. Errors:

1 error occurred:
* failed to bind with current password: 1 error occurred:
* LDAP Result Code 49 "Invalid Credentials": 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090434, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data
52e, v4f7c


Need to create Static role in Ldap secret engine

Did you configure the ldap engine with an ad account that is able to make changes to other accounts?
